# Unexpected response code from CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(..)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When trying to do a batch insert to Azure Table Storage, I am getting a `StorageException` on `CloudTable.ExecuteBatch()`:

```
TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    batchOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
}

table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
```

**Exception thrown:**

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unexpected response
>   code for operation : 6    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](StorageCommandBase1
>   cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in
>   e:\projects\azure-sdk-for-net\microsoft-azure-api\Services\Storage\Lib\DotNetCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   737    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableBatchOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient
>   client, String tableName, TableRequestOptions requestOptions,
>   OperationContext operationContext) in
>   e:\projects\azure-sdk-for-net\microsoft-azure-api\Services\Storage\Lib\DotNetCommon\Table\TableBatchOperation.cs:line
>   85    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(TableBatchOperation
>   batch, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext
>   operationContext) in
>   e:\projects\azure-sdk-for-net\microsoft-azure-api\Services\Storage\Lib\DotNetCommon\Table\CloudTable.cs:line
>   165    at
>   Library.Modules.Cloud.TableStorage.StorageTableRepository`1.InsertOrReplaceBatch(List`1
>   entities)

Inserting these entities normally using `TableOperation` gives me no problems.

I cannot find this exception anywhere on the internet or in the MSDN references.

Comment: Can you check if all entities in the batch 1) are having same PartitionKey and 2) an entity is not repeated more than once in the batch. Based on the error message, look at the 7th entity in your batch. That entity is causing problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was due to duplicate `RowKey` values.  Even with `TableBatchOperation.InsertOrReplace(entities)`, the row keys still need to be unique.

`Unexpected response code for operation : 6` was referring to the 6th element in the list.  The error codes in the Azure SDK are very misleading in my opinion.

Comment: The error codes are indeed misleading. I put together a [guide to using Fiddler to debug this error](http://amadeusw.com/debugging/debugging-azure-with-fiddler/). Use it to find meaningful error information. In my case, the data I've sent was too large.

Comment: @AmadeuszWieczorek Can confirm. Link is broken.

Comment: I had an issue with blogging engine, it's now fixed. Thanks for heads up! The link will now work.